# What does the "i" flag mean in lsof?

Tags: ubuntu, lsof

I was trying to figure out what ports are in use on my Linux Ubuntu machine. I was reading the article *[How to check if port is in use on Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/)* and saw one of their commands was:

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

I am still getting my feet wet with a lot of Linux commands, but I had just recently learned about [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) for listing all open files, so I wanted to understand what these flags were for.

(And what are the -P and -n flags for? I have looked at the manual, but it’s simply not helping. It seems that the -i flag is the most important one here.)

I found that if I did a grep for 'LISTEN' without the -i flag, I got totally different results than with.

In the manual, it says this:

> -i [i]
> This option selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i. If no address is specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.

I really don't understand what this means, and definitely don't understand how it helps me figure out what ports are in use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-i` selects Internet files or sockets. It works with an optional address parameter. Without that parameter, it selects all sockets.

You can use additional filters with this option to select by IPv4/IPv6, by TCP/UDP and so on. The manpage lists several examples:

- `-i 4` to select IPv4 sockets, `-i 6` to select IPv6 sockets.
- `-i TCP` or `-i UDP` to select by protocol.
- `-i @hostname`or `-i @ipaddress` to select by the name/IP of the interface the socket is bound to.
- `-i :port`to select sockets bound to a specific port.

To illustrate the other two options, consider the following example. This entry is from my system, showing two CUPS ports:

```
cupsd      855   root    9u  IPv6  25870      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd      855   root   10u  IPv4  25871      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
```

You'll notice that the port is specified as `ipp` - the Internet Printing Protocol. To turn that back to a number, the `-P` option is used:

```
cupsd      855   root    9u  IPv6  25870      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      855   root   10u  IPv4  25871      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
```

The hostname is displayed as localhost here. In larger networks, `lsof` will make an effort to list the hostnames by looking them up. As an optimization, you can skip that hostname resolution step with `-n`. With `-n`, the IP addresses are shown instead of the hostnames:

```
cupsd      855   root    9u  IPv6  25870      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      855   root   10u  IPv4  25871      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
```

---

As an aside, I like to use the `ss` command to keep track of listening ports. The syntax I commonly use is `ss -ltnp`, which says: 1) show listening ports, 2) only TCP ports, 3) no hostname lookup, 4) show process IDs. The result looks like this (same CUPS ports):

```
LISTEN    0         5                127.0.0.1:631              0.0.0.0:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=855,fd=10))              
LISTEN    0         5                    [::1]:631                 [::]:*        users:(("cupsd",pid=855,fd=9))
```